# Powershell script to populate CheckinNote values in TFS 2010

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am unable to send checkin notes with `workspace.checkin` method in my powershell script. How can I create custom check in notes and send them in powershell script?
I am using TFS 2010

```
$pendingChanges = $workspace.GetPendingChanges();
$checkinnote = @{"Some Note"="some value"}
$changesetNumber = $workspace.CheckIn($pendingChanges ,"Comment", $checkinnote,null,null);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on being "unable to". What error or unexpected behavior are you observing? Remember to replace `null` with the `$null` variable

Comment: To continue from Mathias' comment. In its current form it will expect a cmdlet, exe, function called `null` and you should get an error stating just that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pendingChanges = $workspace.GetPendingChanges();
$checkinNoteFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.CheckinNoteFieldValue 'Some Note', 'some value'
$checkinNote = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.CheckinNote @($checkinNoteFieldValue)
$changesetNumber = $workspace.CheckIn($pendingChanges, 'Comment', $checkinNote, $null, $null)
```

The CheckIn method expects type CheckinNote and a CheckinNote is constructed from an array of CheckinNoteFieldValue objects.